# PHP - Jquery contact form sends blank emails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I've been searching for a solution. Seen other topics, none was helpful so far. So wanted to ask mine. Sorry if it's duplicating another question.

Here is my html markup in `<head></head>`

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     ....
    <style>
    .error { display:none; }
    .success { display:none; }
    </style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#send_message').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var error = false;
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var message = $('#message').val();
            if(name.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
            }
            if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
                var error = true;
                $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
            }
            if(message.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
            } if(error == false){
                $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Gönderiliyor...' });
                $.post("send_message.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                    if(result == 'sent'){
                        $('#cf_submit_p').remove();
                        $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                    } else {
                        $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                        $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Gönder');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

in `<body></body>`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                        <p id="returnmessage"></p>
                        <form action="send_message.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
                            <h2 style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;font-weight:600;padding-bottom:0;">Bize Yazın</h2>
                            <ul class="contactform">
                                <li>
                                    <div id="name_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen adınızı giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon" style="text-align:left"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="text" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="name" id="name" value="" class="required requiredField" placeholder="Ad Soyad"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div id="email_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen eposta adresinizi giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="email" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required requiredField email" placeholder="Eposta"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="textarea">
                                    <div id="message_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen mesajınızı giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <textarea name="message" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" id="message" rows="6" cols="20" class="required requiredField" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="mail_success" class="success" style="color:#00CC00"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> İlginiz için teşekkürler. En kısa sürede sizinle irtibata geçeceğiz.</div>
                                    <div id="mail_fail" class="error" style="color:#aa3939"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Üzgünüz, mesajınız iletilemedi. Daha sonra lütfen tekrar deneyin.</div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="buttons">
                                    <input type="hidden" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                    <button type="submit" style="border:1px solid #3f97cf" class="button cf_submit_p" id="send_message"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#3f97cf"></i></button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div> <!--end container-fluid-->
```

and in send_message.php file;

```
    <?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    //önce değişkenleri topluyoruz.
    $email_to =   'yeterkara90@gmail.com'; //epostanın gönderileceği adres
    $name     =   $_POST['name'];
    $email    =   $_POST['email'];
    $message  =   $_POST['message'];

    $msgTo = "From: $name \r\nEmail: $email \r\nMessage: \r\n$message";

    /*$header değişkeni ilave olanaklar için. Böylelikle yanıtla ya da ilet dediğimizde,
     posta kutusu kime cevap vereceğini bilecek */
    $headers  = "FROM: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "REPLY-TO: $email\r\n";


    if(mail($email_to, $msgTo, $headers)){
        echo 'sent'; // Mailin gönderildiğini AJAXa paslıyoruz.
    }else{
        echo 'failed';// ... ya da gönderilemediğini
    }

}
?>
```

There's something missing, checked the class and id names many times, tried altering the names many times, but I guess, the form does not get the values.. The validation part works great, even displays success message after submit, and sends emails too.. But only the From, Message, Email parts, not the variables.

Can you please help.

Regards,

Vis.

Comment: Look at the function arguments for mail

Comment: Thanks for the replies Dagon and McRossan.. any body text ? sorry couldn't get it.

Comment: $Msgto is the email subject line and $headers the body

Answer (score 2):

Your form id is **contactForm** and your are using **#contact_form**

Comment: Now I have a new problem, after the message was sent, there was a success message on the contact page, now it redirects me to another page where it says "sent" (which isn't a surprise). How to prevent redirecting to another page ? and stay at where I was ?

Comment: Gaurav Saxena, that solved the question but caused another issue. Now it redirects me to another page, which I did not want. e

Comment: Use $.ajax instead of $.post